# how to bound a Persistent volume claim with a gcePersistentDisk?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, persistent-volumes, persistent-volume-claims, gce-persistent-disk

I would like to bound PersistentVolumeClaim with a gcePersistentDisk PersistentVolume. Below the steps I did for getting that:

## 1. Creation of the gcePersistentDisk:

`gcloud compute disks create --size=2GB --zone=us-east1-b gce-nfs-disk`

## 2. Definition the PersistentVolume and the PersistentVolumeClaim

```
# pv-pvc.yml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: nfs-pv
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 2Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  gcePersistentDisk:
    pdName: gce-nfs-disk
    fsType: ext4
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: nfs-pvc
  labels:
    app: test
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 2Gi
```

After running `kubectl apply -f pv-pvc.yml`, the `nfs-pvc` is not bound with `nfs-pv`. In fact, below is the list of the PersistentVolume and PersistentVolumeClaim I have:

```
$ kubectl get pv
NAME                                       CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS      CLAIM             STORAGECLASS   REASON    AGE
nfs-pv                                     2Gi        RWO            Retain           Available                                              30s
pvc-16e4cdf2-cd3d-11e7-83ae-42010a8e0243   2Gi        RWO            Delete           Bound       default/nfs-pvc   standard                 26s
$ kubectl get pvc
NAME      STATUS    VOLUME                                     CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
nfs-pvc   Bound     pvc-16e4cdf2-cd3d-11e7-83ae-42010a8e0243   2Gi        RWO            standard       59s
```

The obtained PersistentVolume is a volume on the disk of the node I created on Google Container Engine. 
So, have I missed something?

PS: the version of kubernetes

```
$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"8", GitVersion:"v1.8.3", GitCommit:"f0efb3cb883751c5ffdbe6d515f3cb4fbe7b7acd", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-11-08T18:39:33Z", GoVersion:"go1.8.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"7+", GitVersion:"v1.7.8-gke.0", GitCommit:"a7061d4b09b53ab4099e3b5ca3e80fb172e1b018", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-10-10T18:48:45Z", GoVersion:"go1.8.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Comment: Name of your PV is my-pvc as well as PVC is my-pvc.However, In the result of commands 'Kubectl get pv,pvc' name is different which are nfd-pv, nfs-pvc.  Why is this behaviour?

Comment: I got your point. Original names are put back. But, any way, the problem is still here...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found the solution.

Below the new definitions of the PV and PVC:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: nfs-pv
  labels:
    app: test  # the label has been added to make sure the bounding is working as expected
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 2Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  gcePersistentDisk:
    pdName: gce-nfs-disk
    fsType: ext4
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: nfs-pvc
  labels:
    app: test
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  storageClassName: "" # the storageClassName has to be specified
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 2Gi
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test
```

After these modifications, this is the bounding worked:

```
$ kubectl get pvc
NAME      STATUS    VOLUME    CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
nfs-pvc   Bound     nfs-pv    2Gi        RWO                           8s
$ kubectl get pv
NAME      CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS    CLAIM             STORAGECLASS   REASON    AGE
nfs-pv    2Gi        RWO            Retain           Bound     default/nfs-pvc                            22m
```

I hope it will help.

Comment: Getting this error on using volume as above. Failed to get GCE GCECloudProvider with error <nil>

Answer (score 2):

With **PersistentVolumeClaim**, you don't need to create **PersistentVolume** objects or **gcePersistentDisk**. Instead, create only a PVC and Kubernetes automatically creates a PV object that references the backing storage.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: nfs-pvc
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  storageClassName: ssd-sc  # specify the storage class created below
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi
```

Create a **StorageClass** so it knows which backing storage to use. You can specify that it retains the storage (**reclaimPolicy: Retain**) if you delete the PVC and the storage type (**type: pd-ssd**).

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: ssd-sc 
provisioner: kubernetes.io/gce-pd
reclaimPolicy: Retain # Retain storage even if we delete PVC
parameters:
  type: pd-ssd # ssd
```